# R How to change format of date from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYYMMDD and YY-Month (Abbreviated Month)?

Tags: r, date

I have a column called `data$Month`. The data in that column is formatted like 11/30/2018. I would like to change the format to 20181130 and 18-Nov and use that in other columns.

I've tried this.

```
data$Month2 <- format(as.Date(data$Month, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y%M%D")
data$Month3 <- format(as.Date(data$Month, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%m")
data$tranId=paste("EXAMPLE","_",data$Month2)
data$postingperiod=data$Month3
data$Month2<-NULL
data$Month3<-NULL
```

But, I get data that looks like  Example_ 20180011/30/18 and 2017-11, respectively. Also, I feel like the code could be simplified, I'm going to be running this in a loop and would like to not have to use as many functions if possible. I'm sure it's a simple solution but I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your dates are formatted correctly i.e. they are not factors -

```
x <- as.Date("11/30/2018", format = "%m/%d/%Y")

paste0("Example_", format.Date(x, "%Y%m%d"))
[1] "Example_20181130"

format.Date(x, "%y-%b")
[1] "18-Nov"
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error in format.Date(data$Month, "%Y%m%d") %>% paste0("Example_",  : 
  could not find function "%>%"`

Comment: When I use data$Month, I'm getting this. I didn't run the first line but wasn't sure what to do with the first line when I have multiple dates, not just 11/30/2018 `data$tranId=paste0(acronym[0],"_", format.Date(data$Month, "%Y%m%d"))
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
data$postingperiod=format.Date(data$Month, "%y-%b")
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: Wait, I think this worked. `x <- as.Date(data$Month, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` Thanks!

Comment: @JNietert consider marking this correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hey, I'm working with some different data but am wanting to run a similar line of code. However when I run `x <- as.Date(data$Month, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` I am just getting NAs and not the dates when I do `head(x)`.

Comment: @JNietert Make `data$Month` a character if it is a factor. If not then a post a separate question with some values from `data$Month`.

Comment: I don't think that was it, but I'm only working on one (large) file so it is simple enough to just concatenate instead of continuing to troubleshoot.